# How can I tell if XCode version 14.2 is stuck on installation? Any way to see percent complete?

Tags: xcode, macos, upgrade, xcode14

I'm currently installing (Upgrading to) XCode 14.2 and it has been running for a long time.
This is taking longer than my last macOS update.

I currently see the following which only shows a spinner and no update progress.

[image: xcode update, spinner]

Floating over the spinner does not give you anything.

I've also looked in Launcher and all I see is this:

[image: xcode installing icon in launcher]

Is there any way to see the percent complete?

Comment: I’d recommend not using the AppStore but instead installing Xcodes and using that to update. `brew install —cask xcodes`

Comment: what is xcodes?

Comment: It’s a small app that makes it really easy to manage updating and having multiple versions of Xcode. It also doesn’t use the monumentally slow AppStore download and install so you don’t have to wait hours for it.

Comment: https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes

Comment: No worries. A colleague introduced it to me and I won’t go without it now. 

Comment: I'd recommend downloading and installing Xcode from developer.apple.com instead of AppStore.

Comment: Here's the link to the developer download area where you can get XCode : https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get a percent complete you'll have to do the following:

1. Close the App Store
2. Open the App Store again
3. search for XCode so it displays the available apps to install.
4. float over the spinning cursor in this window (shown below).

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped. I've been waiting 4 hours for xcode 14.2 to finished updating thinking it was stuck but at least now I can see what percentage is left.